# service oriented architecture for dependency of records

Tags: architecture, soa

I have created two services. one for producer and one for consumer. when any record delete from database which is consume by consumer. Consumer is not aware of such delete operation. when consumer ask for this records producer is not sending dependent record so null display consumer side. (As we have not maintain PK and FK relation ship between producer and consumer database) how should we have to handle such scenario in service oriented architecture?

Thanks.

Comment: "When consumer ask for this records" does not make sense in a consumer in a consumer/producer pattern.  Producers produce, consumers consume.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. Returning null from producer means that the record was deleted. Depending on the context logic you have consumer might check for the existence and delete its DB record to preserve referential integrity. Or you might disable delete in producer and set deactivate column. Or, since you've mentioned SOA, you might use ESB and update all services in one transaction.

Comment: Thanks all for your views.